# Turn Ruby Mysql query into variable

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the username as a ruby variable however I end up getting the following

```
{"username"=>"test"}
```

I only want the username text in this case it is test.

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "",                  :database =>"test")
results = client.query("SELECT username FROM accounts").each do |row|
    puts row [0]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can work with the [old mysql/ruby adapter](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/), but not mysql2. By default, mysql2 returns a `Hash` for each row.

So you can either

1. `puts row['username']`
2. use `each(:as => :array)` to have the old behaviour.

See [GitHub mysql2 project](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)

Maybe you can simplify your code:

```
 results = client.query("SELECT username FROM Accounts").each(:as => :array)
 puts results
```

Here `results` will be an `Array` of all the use names.

A full working program:

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "", :password => "",
                            :database =>"test")

results = client.query("SELECT * FROM Movie").each(:as => :array)
results.each { | row | puts row.join("\t") }
```

Comment: Hey @prnoo thank you for your response I'm currently getting syntax errors with your second option any ideas?

Comment: Just added a working test. I am using ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]. Good luck :-)